# How to get all values when I minus two tables in oracle

Tags: sql, oracle

I have two tables say table1 and table2

table1 has duplicate rows but table2 may or may not have
when I do

```
select * from table1 minus select * from table2
```

I get unique values of table1 but i need duplicates value to come

Comment: Please, post sample data and desired output.

Answer (score 3):

If you have a key (a field or several fields which allow you to know if one line of `table1` matches another line in `table2`), you could use `exist`:

```
select *
from table1 t1
where not exists (select 1 from table2 t2 where t2.pk_field = t1.pk_field)
```

If you don't have a PK, you will have to specify all fields:

```
select *
from table1 t1
where not exists (select 1 from table2 t2 where t2.field1 = t1.field1
                                            and t2.field2 = t1.field2 ...)
```

**EDIT:** here is a basic example:

```
with table1 as
(
  select 1 a from dual
  union all
  select 1 a from dual
  union all
  select 2 a from dual
  union all
  select 2 a from dual
  union all
  select 3 a from dual
),
table2 as
(
  select 2 a from dual
)
select *
from table1 t1
where not exists (select 1 from table2 t2 where t2.a = t1.a)
```

The result is correct, 1 is shown twice:

```
Row #   A
1   1
2   1
3   3
```

Comment: Shouldn't that just be `exists` rather than `not exists`? They want rows where there is a duplicate, not the ones where there isn't. Possible I've misunderstood the question though.

Comment: @AnthonyGrist . . . I think the OP wants everything in `table1` that is not in `table2`, including any duplicates in `table1`.

Comment: yeah, but i am getting same values as minus. actually i ve four duplicates in table1, which exists only once in table2.. so ideally it should return other 3 but it dint return any of it

Comment: Well, please take a look at my edit - that looks correct on my side.